# Black UIViewController toolbar?

Tags: iphone

Could you please share the command that makes the toolbar i.e. the one that contains the UIVIewController.toolbarItems black instead of grey?

Thank you,

F.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "command" in the iPhone SDK that allows you to change the colour of bar button items from grey to black. To do that, you will have to design and draw your own custom toolbar by subclassing `UIView`.

Comment: Pity! :P Thank you for the info! F.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.tintColor` property of the toolbar to `[UIColor blackColor]`. This is easy in Interface Builder, in code you must have a reference to the toolbar, e.g. via an `IBOutlet`.

(did you mean *tab*-bar? if so, see Jonathans answer: you cannot)

Comment: Mvds thank you. Could I use IBOutlet even if I don't have a xib file at all? F.

Comment: @nosuic no you can't. My advice is to invest some time in mastering Interface Builder (IB) since it will save you a lot of work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I feel I came very close using the `UIToolbar` class following the article below:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43658/How-to-Make-a-Toolbar-with-UIToolbar.aspx

With very few lines of code I was able to show the toolbar exactly as I wanted. However it doesn't seem to respond at touching.

I'll get away with the blue bars for now, didn't think it would be That tricky to change the toolbar colour!